# How to assign an event to a variable in jQuery

Tags: jquery, variables, events

Without using anything that has been deprecated (ie: `.bind()`), is there a way to assign an event to a variable so we can turn off that exact event later?  For example, if we have:

```
$(window).on('resize', function() {
    alert('Hello!');
});
```

Can we target the function call from that event later and remove it from the resize event?  We may have other $(window).on('resize') calls, but I do not want to deactivate those function calls on those events.

If we did `$(window).off('resize');`, that would turn off that event for all of them.

Comment: Possibly. I would first test with the Event object itself. Pass in a `e` or `event` in your function and store that event to a variable. For more help, please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Use the jquery event namespace option, eg `$(window).on("resize.myevent"...`   `$(window).off("resize.myevent")`

Comment: freedomn-m, very nice, thanks.  I did not know you could namespace events.  That will do the trick is targeting specific events and their respective function calls.

Answer (score 1):

You could name the function, and reference it after in vanilla JS

```
var myCallable = function() { alert(“Hello World”); }

// add the event listener
window.addEventListener(‘resize’, myCallable);
window.addEventListener(‘resize’, function() {
  alert(“this call won’t be removed”);
});

// remove it later on...
window.removeEventListener(‘resize’, myCallable);
```

This will only remove that specific function call because you’re referencing it directly

Note: forgive the punctuation, I’m typing this on an iPhone

Comment: That works, thank you.  But I think the event namespace option will do the trick in a more elegant (turn on and off the entire event + associated function calls) way.